# database modeling: null foreign keys by entity type

Tags: database, laravel, oop, relational-database, relationship

I need some help designing my database relationships.
I have these tables: documents, companies, individuals and users. A document can be internal or external.

- If it is external, it can be signed by a company or an individual.
- If it is internal it has to be signed by a user.

In any case, the document is signed by a single entity (company, individual or user). I was thinking of creating the documents table in the following way:

```
documents
----------
id_document
...
type
id_user
id_company
id_indiv
```

where `type` can be 0: internal, 1: external and `id_user`, `id_company`, `id_indiv` are foreign keys of the respective tables and can be null. Is this logic okay? Can someone suggest me a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's `Eloquent ORM` provides the `Polymorphic` relationship to handle this kind of problem.

To be more specific, you can place two fields; `documentable_type` and `documentable_id` inside your `document` table. And then add these relationship methods to each model;

```
class Document extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the owning imageable model.
     */
    public function signer()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the documents signed by this user.
     */
    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Document', 'documentable');
    }
}

class Company extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the documents signed by this company.
     */
    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Document', 'documentable');
    }
}

class Individual extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the documents signed by this individual.
     */
    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Document', 'documentable');
    }
}
```

Then you can use the following snippets;

```
$document->signer; // This returns either user or company or individual
$company->documents; // This returns a collection of document models which is signed by this company
$individual->documents;
$user->documents;
```

For more details, see this link; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Comment: I really like your answer. But I have a doubt. Company, individual an user are old tables and I can't modify it. For example individal has two columns: first_name, last name, company has: bussines_name and user has a column called: names. How can I get a list of documents including its singer name. ```class Individual: public function name() { return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name; }```
```class Company: public function name() { return $this->bussines_name; }``` So I can do $document->signer->name(); that's right?

Comment: Type of `$document->signer` varies in different contexts. As I mentioned in answer, it can be neither `User` model or `Company` model or `Individual` model. So it is a good idea to add common methods named `name()` for each model.

Comment: Or also define custom accessor (e.g. `getNameAttribute`).